# How to get only specified item from list of "tr" tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get only one item from a list of tags:

Here is a sample of the code, simplified :

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>Intro</tr>
  <tr>
   <td>First data</td>
   <td>Second data</td>
   <td>Third data</td>
   <td>Fourth data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>First data</td>
   <td>Second data</td>
   <td>Third data</td>
   <td>Fourth data</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm interested only in "Second data" and "Third data"

Here's what I have:

```
table = soup.find_all("table")

children_tr = table[3].findChildren("tr")

for child_td in children_tr[1:]:
  for child in child_td:
    try:
      print(child)
    except AttributeError:
      print("")
```

Like this I can get in order

```
First data
Second data
Third data
Fourth data
```

I can't figure out how to get only "First data" and "Second data"

Edit: there are multiple  from which I need the first and second

Comment: just use index slicing for example, `print(child_td[0])` and `print(child_td[1])`

Comment: table = soup.findAll('td')[1:3]
for t in table:
    print(t.contents[0])

Second data
Third data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`nth-of-type(n)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) CSS selector.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>Intro</tr>
  <tr>
   <td>First data</td>
   <td>Second data</td>
   <td>Third data</td>
   <td>Fourth data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>First data</td>
   <td>Second data</td>
   <td>Third data</td>
   <td>Fourth data</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.select("tr td:nth-of-type(2), td:nth-of-type(3)"):
    print(tag.text)
```

Output:

```
Second data
Third data
Second data
Third data
```

Answer (score 0):

> I can't figure out how to get only "First data" and "Second data"

```py
table = soup.findAll('td')[:2] 
for t in table: 
    print(t.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked out this solution:

```
for child_td in children_tr[1:]:
  for child in child_td:
    try:
      temp_list.insert(0,child.text)
    except AttributeError:
      continue
  max_temperature.append(temp_list[3])
print(max_temperature)
```

Like this I end up with a list of the "Second data"

Not the most elegant solution, if any of you know of a better way please let me know